# Differentiate Route Based On QueryString in Web API

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have an ApiController where I have 2 actions:

`public IEnumerable<Users> GetUsers(){}`

`public IHttpActionResult UsersPagination(int startindex = 0, int size = 5, string sortby = "Username", string order = "DESC"){}`

Since I have default routing like below:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

I get the error:

`Multiple actions were found that match the request: 
GetUsers on type HomeBook.API.Controllers.UsersController 
UsersPagination on type HomeBook.API.Controllers.UsersController`

Basically, I want 2 actions in my controller: one that returns all users another returns a pagination form of users. Like here: http://dev.librato.com/v1/pagination

Please suggest how I can achieve this.

Comment: If you are returning same list of records, you don't need to create multiple actions. You can achieve it with single action only

Comment: @irvgk No obviously not. They have different responses. Here is same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24774910/differentiating-get-method-containing-query-string-in-asp-net-web-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, WebApi uses a convention to map request to specific action methods. With the current setup it cannot decide which of the two methods should be used. You can read more about WebApi routing here - [Routing in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)

Once way to resolve such problems is to use Attribute Routing. As the name suggest with this technique attributes are used to control how requests are mapped to action methods. You can read more about Attribute routing here - http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

To solve your problem with attribute routing you can use the following setup:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/pagination")]
public class MyController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("users")]
    public IEnumerable<Users> GetUsers() { }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("users-paginated")]
    public IHttpActionResult UsersPagination(int startindex = 0, int size = 5, string sortby = "Username", string order = "DESC") { }
}
```

Now, if you make a request to `api/pagination/users` then `GetUsers()` will be invoked. Similarly, if you make a request to `api/pagination/users-paginated` then `UsersPagination()` will be invoked.